# API for specific users WSO2 Api Manager

Tags: wso2

How can I set some APIs that I create it in in Publisher portal for specific users??

Which I want it when some user open his Devportal he will see only the APIs private for him

Anyone know please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to that which are control API visibility in the Developer Portal and control subscription availability in Developer Portal. This doc will help you to do that,
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/advanced-topics/control-api-visibility-and-subscription-availability-in-developer-portal/